Python can't access FFmpeg binary in /data/user/0/com.app.name/files/ in Android Studio
I'm a beginner in android development (and java). I'm making a hybrid application in java which runs python (using chaquopy).
MainActivity.java runs the python script fine, the only problem is that the yt_dlp library that I've used can't access FFmpeg.
The FFmpeg binary file (for linuxarm64, I don't think that's the problem) is located in the assets folder (src/main/assets), then it's copied to /data/user/0/com.app.name/files :
//FileUtils.java
public class FileUtils {
    public static void copyAsset(Context context, String assetName, String outputPath) {
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream in = assetManager.open(assetName);
            File outFile = new File(outputPath);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();

            // Set executable permissions for the binary
            outFile.setExecutable(true);  // Ensure the file is executable
            outFile.setReadable(true);
            outFile.setWritable(true);
            Log.d("FileUtils", "FFmpeg File - Exists: " + outFile.exists() +
                    ", Executable: " + outFile.canExecute());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


//MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private pyRun pyrun;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 123;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("YTDownloader", "onCreate: Starting...");
        String ffmpegPath = getFilesDir() + "/ffmpeg";

        // Copy the binary
        FileUtils.copyAsset(this, "ffmpeg", ffmpegPath);

        // Check if file exist and log
        Log.d(TAG, "FFmpeg exists: " + new File(ffmpegPath).exists());
        Log.d(TAG, "PATH: "+ffmpegPath);

        //load python
        //load webview
    }
    //other functions
}

And finally it should be loaded by yt_dlp in python:
import os
import yt_dlp as youtube_dl
ffmpeg_path='/data/user/0/com.dudek3d.ytdownloader/files/ffmpeg'

ydl_opts = {
'ffmpeg_location': ffmpeg_path,
'format': 'bestvideo+bestaudio/best',
'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegVideoConvertor',
        'preferedformat': 'mp4'}],
'noplaylist': True,
'quiet': True,
'merge_output_format': 'mp4',
'outtmpl': filename+'.%(ext)s',
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])

The downloaded file is corrupted because FFmpeg is not found.
I've found out that ffmpeg file cannot be accessed from neither Java nor Python.
I've tried:
1)
Changing the paths to cache: ffmpeg_path='/data/user/0/com.dudek3d.ytdownloader/cache/ffmpeg'
Changing the paths to data: ffmpeg_path='/data/data/com.dudek3d.ytdownloader/files/ffmpeg'
Changing the paths to data cache: ffmpeg_path='/data/data/com.dudek3d.ytdownloader/cache/ffmpeg'
2)
Accessing ffmpeg path from MainActivity.java and got "Permission Denied" Error, so I added
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

to AndroidManifest.xml but still the same error occurs.
3)
Using ffmpeg implementations in dependecies in build.gradle (app Module) such as: 'com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-full:4.5'
but this won't work because I think that's accessible by java and not python.
4)
I've changed location of ffmpeg to src/main/jniLibs/arc64-v8a:
ffmpegPath = getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/ffmpeg";
passed that to python:
def run(format_choice, listt, ffmpeg_pat, ffprobe_pat):
    global ffmpeg_path, ffprobe_path
    ffmpeg_path, ffprobe_path= ffmpeg_pat, ffprobe_pat

but I got:
WARNING: ffmpeg-location /data/app/~~42sSKOephY26jjdLYW7wmw==/com.dudek3d.ytdownloader-OWqWbazkZobYNlsqTsxfyA==/lib/x86_64/ffmpeg does not exist!
I hope it's clear, thanks in advance.

As discussed here, on recent versions of Android, the only way for an app to run its own executables is to bundle them in the APK's lib directory and use extractNativeLibs to make sure they exist as separate files at runtime. For FFmpeg, there are some alternative approaches at https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/143.
